Minimum distance from a point to a set
If $S=\{(x,y,z)|x^2+y^2+z^2 \leq 4, x^2-4y \leq 0\}$ and $w=(1,0,2)^t$. Find the minimum distance of $w$ to $S$, the unique minimizing point and the separating plane.
Solve without using KKT conditions.
I know the distance is $d^2=(x-1)^2+y^2+(z-2)^2$ and the minimizing point has to be on the border of the sphere or on the parabola.
So far I've tried substituting $x^2+y^2+z^2=4$ in the distance formula and I get $d^2=9-2x-4z$, then I calculate the gradient in order to find the critical points but it turns out to be $\Delta d(x,z)=(-2,-4)$ meaning it does not have critical points.
Something similar happens when I substitute with the parabola equation.
What is the correct way to do this?
